# Programmatically create auto generated coupon codes in Magento?

Tags: magento, coupon

Based on other stackoverflow posts, I've been able to use the following code to programmatically generate individual shopping cart price rule coupons in Magento.

How can I programmatically call the "Auto Generate Coupon" feature to create 100 unique coupons for each price rule I make? Thanks!

```
$coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
$coupon->setName($_coupon['name'])
       ->setDescription('this is a description')
       ->setFromDate(date('Y-m-d'))
       ->setCouponType(2)
       ->setCouponCode($_coupon['code'])
       ->setUsesPerCoupon(1000)
       ->setUsesPerCustomer(100)
       ->setCustomerGroupIds(array(1)) //an array of customer groupids
       ->setIsActive(1)
       //serialized conditions.  the following examples are empty
       ->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
       ->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
       ->setStopRulesProcessing(0)
       ->setIsAdvanced(1)
       ->setProductIds('')
       ->setSortOrder(0)
       ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
       ->setDiscountAmount(100)
       ->setDiscountQty(null)
       ->setDiscountStep('0')
       ->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
       ->setApplyToShipping('0')
       ->setIsRss(0)
       ->setWebsiteIds(array(1));      
$coupon->save();
```

For instance, this one price rule might have a whole list of Auto-Generated Coupon Codes (htgf-7774, htgf-2345, etc) using the function that is available when manually creating price rules in the admin panel.

**EDIT:**

I've gotten closer, using the following code. Still don't know how to specifically assign the auto generation pattern

```
->setName('Name')
->setDescription('this is a description')
->setFromDate('2013-03-06')
->setToDate(NULL)
->setUsesPerCustomer('100')
->setIsActive('1')
->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:32:"salesrule/rule_condition_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:"type";s:40:"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine";s:9:"attribute";N;s:8:"operator";N;s:5:"value";s:1:"1";s:18:"is_value_processed";N;s:10:"aggregator";s:3:"all";}')
->setStopRulesProcessing('0')
->setIsAdvanced('1')
->setProductIds(NULL)
->setSortOrder('0')
->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
->setDiscountAmount('100.0000')
->setDiscountQty(NULL)
->setDiscountStep('0')
->setSimpleFreeShipping('0')
->setApplyToShipping('0')
->setTimesUsed('1')
->setIsRss('0')
->setCouponType('2')
->setUseAutoGeneration('1')
->setUsesPerCoupon('1000')
->setCustomerGroupIds(array('1',))
->setWebsiteIds(array('1',))
->setCouponCode(NULL)
```

Comment: what magento version is this ?

Comment: version 1.702 (recent install)

Comment: I am pleased to report that this works in Magento 1.9. yay.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to a nifty post I found while googling this (http://fragmentedthought.com/fragments/programatically-creating-sales-rule-coupon-code), I answered my own question:

```
// Get the rule in question
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(21); //21 = ID of coupon in question

// Define a coupon code generator model instance
// Look at Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon_Massgenerator for options
$generator = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon_massgenerator');

$parameters = array(
    'count'=>5,
    'format'=>'alphanumeric',
    'dash_every_x_characters'=>4,
    'prefix'=>'ABCD-EFGH-',
    'suffix'=>'-WXYZ',
    'length'=>8
);

if( !empty($parameters['format']) ){
  switch( strtolower($parameters['format']) ){
    case 'alphanumeric':
    case 'alphanum':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHANUMERIC );
      break;
    case 'alphabetical':
    case 'alpha':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_ALPHABETICAL );
      break;
    case 'numeric':
    case 'num':
      $generator->setFormat( Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_FORMAT_NUMERIC );
      break;
  }
}

$generator->setDash( !empty($parameters['dash_every_x_characters'])? (int) $parameters['dash_every_x_characters'] : 0);
$generator->setLength( !empty($parameters['length'])? (int) $parameters['length'] : 6);
$generator->setPrefix( !empty($parameters['prefix'])? $parameters['prefix'] : '');
$generator->setSuffix( !empty($parameters['suffix'])? $parameters['suffix'] : '');

// Set the generator, and coupon type so it's able to generate
$rule->setCouponCodeGenerator($generator);
$rule->setCouponType( Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO );

// Get as many coupons as you required
$count = !empty($parameters['count'])? (int) $parameters['count'] : 1;
$codes = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
  $coupon = $rule->acquireCoupon();
  $code = $coupon->getCode();
  $codes[] = $code;
}
return $codes;
```

This successfully generated the following codes:

```
ABCD-EFGH-ZC6V-ZJWD-WXYZ
ABCD-EFGH-4XMX-353L-WXYZ
ABCD-EFGH-XCJB-5GQI-WXYZ
ABCD-EFGH-UEAO-L1NJ-WXYZ
ABCD-EFGH-59B3-50T2-WXYZ
```

Comment: This worked for me as described, the codes where generated, but on the frontend I was unable to use the coupon codes because according to Magento the codes where invalid, even though they where visible in the Magento Admin Panel. What I had to change to make them work was to add the following from the link you provided: `$coupon->setType(Mage_SalesRule_Helper_Coupon::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC_AUTOGENERATED)->save();`. This has to be done for each coupon, so ideally it would be added right after the following line in your snippet: `$coupon = $rule->acquireCoupon()`.

Comment: How safe is this? Could this not create a rule which already exists ?

Comment: Thanks @LouisBataillard, it didn't even save the coupons without this line. 
V1.9.2.4