# Magento coupon code generation upon purchase

Tags: magento

I have a scenario, where I use a coupon code and make a purchase. Upon successful purchase I have to generate another coupon code for the customer.
This new coupon code should be generated only after using a specific coupon code for purchase or for specific promotion rule.
I am using community edition.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate coupon code programmatically ..Refer to the below link and insert a check to fulfill your requirement. 
[Programmatically create auto generated coupon codes in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260397/programmatically-create-auto-generated-coupon-codes-in-magento)

Comment: That does not answer to the "upon puchase" part.

Comment: "upon purchase" part is just a check to put in order success flow whether user used specific coupon code/rule or not.